# How to mask the layer of a view by the content of another view?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, calayer

I have a UIImageView and a UILabel, and want the content of the UILabel to mask the UIImageView. The goal is that the text is visible with content of image but everything else transparent.

Is there a simple way to mask a view by the contents of another view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `QuartzCore Framework`.

(Link project with `QuartzCore.framework` and import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>).

```
@import QuartzCore;
```

Background of label must be clear color. Example:

```
self.imageView.layer.mask = self.label.layer;
self.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

**In Interface Builder:**

[image]

**On device:**

[image]

Comment: This only works if the content is in monochrome color space doesn't it?

Comment: No, masking use alpha channel of mask layer.