# Using UILabel as a mask for a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uilabel

I'm trying to create a UILabel mask with an animatable UIView behind it.  I'm trying to use this answer [How to mask the layer of a view by the content of another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998536/how-to-mask-the-layer-of-a-view-by-the-content-of-another-view) but I am not having any luck..

I've created a UIImageView, and a transparent UILabel in my nib.  In in my UIView subclass I do this.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {

    self.imageview.layer.mask = self.label.layer
    self.imageview.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I've also made sure that the two are sitting right on top of eachother.  Is there anything else I should know in order to make this work?   When I run the simulator both the imageview, and the uilabel are missing.  What am I doing wrong?

my uilabel config

[image]

here i try doing this by using a programmatically created UILabel **not** added to a superview

```
    let blah = UILabel(frame: self.asteroid.frame)
    blah.text = "yo yo yo"
    blah.font = UIFont(name: "Estrogen", size: 20)

    self.asteroid.layer.mask = blah.layer
    self.asteroid.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the text colour?

Comment: yes, according to the answer i linked  the text should be transparent.. but ive tried adding a color.  i have the same issue.  nothing shows up

Comment: It seems to me that the *background* of the `UILabel` would be transparent, but the text of the `UILabel` would not be in order for this to work.

Comment: i dont have any background.. i can set the text itself to any color but when i have that code in place, both my imageview, and my label disappear =/

Comment: `UILabel` defaults its background colour to white; you need to set it to clear.

Comment: ive set it to clear in interface builder, i added a picture of my uilabel config

Comment: And you've made sure that you didn't add `self.label` to a view? `mask` layers with `superlayer`s don't usually work well.

Comment: the label exists within interface builder, so i suppose it is a child of a uiview automatically.   I haven't added it to any other view.  In the answer I linked, the person was setting up the elements via IB..  so i figured that was okay?

Comment: i've tried what you suggested

Comment: Try using the `bounds` instead of the `frame`. You'll want to be in the coordinate space of the thing you're trying to mask, making `(0,0)` the origin of the masked layer.

Comment: i tried using bounds too. no good.  have you tried doing this Ian?

Comment: Not with a `UILabel`, no. I have done a lot of work with text rendering on iOS, though, so I'm actually not that surprised to learn that it can't be combined as easily as one might expect. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22672945/2708650 . It's unfortunate that the answer that you posted at the top of your question doesn't work well for you; that would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Look this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671245/objective-c-display-uiview-within-uilabel-text-mask

Comment: i copy pasted the code using obj c and got it to work.. only problem is it doesnt seem animatable (the background image) :(  gonna do more research

Comment: this is really the best way to go about it.. using two images instead of a UILabel

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation

Comment: You can now use the `maskView` property on the `UIView` (added in iOS 8.0) to do this. [See this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35678866/2976878)