# Reverse layer mask for label

Tags: ios, uilabel

How do you reverse the mask layer for a label? I have a `textLabel`, which I use as a mask for an `imageView` that contains an arbitrary image as follows:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "someImage")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

let textLabel = UILabel()
textLabel.frame = imageView.bounds
textLabel.text = "Some text"

imageView.layer.mask = textLabel.layer
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The above makes the text in `textLabel` have a font colour of the `imageView` as in [How to mask the layer of a view by the content of another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998536/how-to-mask-the-layer-of-a-view-by-the-content-of-another-view).

How do I reverse this so as to **remove** the text in `textLabel` **from** the `imageView`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make a subclass of `UILabel`:

```
class InvertedMaskLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
        guard let gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        CGContextSaveGState(gc)
        UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(gc, .Clear)
        super.drawTextInRect(rect)
        CGContextRestoreGState(gc)
    }
}
```

This subclass fills its bounds with an opaque color (white in this example, but only the alpha channel matters). Then it draws the text using the `Clear` blend mode, which simply sets all channels of the context back to 0, including the alpha channel.

Playground demo:

```
let root = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400))
root.backgroundColor = .blueColor()
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = root

let image = UIImage(named: "Kaz-256.jpg")
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
root.addSubview(imageView)

let label = InvertedMaskLabel()
label.text = "Label"
label.frame = imageView.bounds
label.font = .systemFontOfSize(40)
imageView.maskView = label
```

Result:

[image: demo of image transparency inside the label text]

Comment: can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to implement this recently and the syntax has changed a bit, here's a **Swift 4.x Version** of @RobMayoff's excellent answer. Demo/GitHub repo with Swift Playground located [here](https://github.com/JaredHalpern/MaskDemo).

(If you do upvote this, please also upvote his original answer as well :)  )

A playground demonstrating the technique. The method `drawRect` inside `InvertedMaskLabel` has the secret sauce.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// As per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36758946/reverse-layer-mask-for-label

class InvertedMaskLabel: UILabel {

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.saveGState()
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect) // fill bounds w/opaque color
        context.setBlendMode(.clear)
        super.drawText(in: rect) // draw text using clear blend mode, ie: set *all* channels to 0
        context.restoreGState()
    }
}

class TestView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .green

        let image = UIImage(named: "tr")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageview.frame = bounds
        addSubview(imageView)

        let label = InvertedMaskLabel()
        label.text = "Teddy"
        label.frame = imageView.bounds
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)
        imageView.mask = label
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let testView = TestView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 500))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = testView
```